# UDF to Add Number of Days to TimeStamp

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to add 10 days to a current time stamp that I have in a Cosmos collection then compare it to today's date

I am new to using User Defined functions in Cosmos so I would like to get some help with that. An example of a time stamp that I have

```
"MyTimeStamp": "2019-03-17T21:04:37.9149806Z"
```

I would like a UDF that takes that time stamp and adds 10 days to it to output

```
"MyTimeStamp": "2019-03-27T21:04:37.9149806Z"
```

Then after that I would like to compare to query and compare it to the current time using `GetCurrentDateTime()`

So the final SQL query would be

```
SELECT c.MyTimeStamp 
FROM c 
WHERE udf.addTenDays(c.MyTimeStamp) < GetCurrentDateTime()
```

Is that possible in Cosmos Db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert timestamp into unixtime with UDF,then compare them.Please refer to below 2 udfs:

AddTenDays:

```
function test(timestamp){
  var date = new Date(timestamp);
  //add 10 days
  var time = date.getTime()+864000000;
  return time;
}
```

GetCurrentUnixTime:

```
function today(){
   return new Date().getTime();
}
```

SQL:

```
SELECT c.id FROM c
where udf.test(c.MyTimeStamp)<udf.today()
```